# Animate SVG Line from Left to right Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to create an animated line as if its being drawn from one point to another. I have managed to get the line drawing on to the page but can't work out how to animate it as if it's being drawn?

https://jsfiddle.net/0sdt33dz/

```
function svgAnimate (){
var s = Snap('#svg');
var linePath = "M-3,148.6c0,0,43.9,7,49.4-17.2c3.5-15.3-9.4-19.7-17.3-13.8c-6,4.4-10,19,11.3,25.4 c24.9,7.5,70.7-31.2,91-61.8S233-41.5,286.3,29.2c0,0-60.7,35.5-24.9,87.9c36.2,53,83.5,15.6,83.5,15.6s19.3,19.5,68.4,17.1";
var lineLength = Snap.path.getTotalLength(linePath);
var lineDraw = s.path(linePath);
lineDraw.attr({
    fill:'none',
    stroke:'#009FE3',
    'stroke-width' :6,
    'stroke-linecap' :'round',
    'stroke-linejoin' :'round',
    'stroke-miterlimit' :10
});
lineDraw.animate({
    stroke : '#fff'
},3000, mina.easein)
console.log(lineLength);
}
svgAnimate();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, just missing two things.

First, you need to set the `stroke-dasharray` to `'<length> <length>'`, this will create a "dashed" line with gaps/fill equal to the length of the entire line

```
lineDraw.attr({
    fill:'none',
    stroke:'#009FE3',
    'stroke-dasharray': lineLength + ' ' + lineLength,
    'stroke-dashoffset': lineLength,
    'stroke-width' :6,
    ...
```

After this you need to animate the offset of the stroke to `0` using `stoke-dashoffset`

```
lineDraw.animate({
    strokeDashoffset : 0
},3000, mina.easein)
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foozle/0sdt33dz/1/)

Comment: Spot on thanks! Could you explain what: lineLength + ' ' + lineLength does?

Comment: That sets the different spacings you want in your line, so you can build a dasharray line up of something like "10 5" (will repeat that), or more complex, eg "10 20 30 5 10 20" dictating the spaces and string dashes.

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = Snap("#myLine");

//Line parameters (x1, y1, x2, y2)
var line = s.line(30, 45, 30, 45);
line.attr({
    stroke: "#000",
    strokeWidth: 2
});

//Old x2 values is 30 and now it is increasing to 70 with 1 second duration
line.animate({x2: 70}, 1000);
```

I hope this answer will help you!